# Testing app on emulator for specific configuration

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am new to android development. There is one project that runs fine on 10.1 inch Samsung tablet but UI get distorted when run on Sony Xperia Z Tablet. I had created separate layout folder named layout-sw800dp-land for Sony Xperia Z Tablet (10.1 inch) and calculated smallest with the following method.

```
  dp = px/(dpi/160)
     =1200/(240/160)
     =800
```

Specification for XperiaZ Tablet can be found on this link:-
http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_tablet_z_wi_fi-5326.php

Now i do not have access to device, so i need to test it on emulator but there is no emulator available for screen configuration 1200X1920.

How could i test code on emulator for some particular screen configuration?? Is there any way to create AVD with own device apart from default available devices??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get the right AVDs is to install the Sony developer SDK. See this:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/install-detailed-instructions/#installdefinitions

Answer (score 0):

The 'clone avd' option in avd manager allows you to create your own size and required avds.